# sql server select the first occurrence of data change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, gaps-and-islands

I have a **sql server 2008 r2** database.

I have a table called `hystrealdata` in which are stored production data of an automotiv machine every *n seconds*. Thus, it is structured like this:

```
dataregvalue                                        timestamp             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                                                   1507190476            
0                                                   1507190577            
0                                                   1507190598            
0                                                   1507190628            
1                                                   1507190719            
1                                                   1507190750            
1                                                   1507190780            
1                                                   1507190811            
1                                                   1507190841            
2                                                   1507190861            
2                                                   1507190892            
2                                                   1507190922            
2                                                   1507190953            
2                                                   1507190983      
5                                                   1507190477
```

I need to select the first occurrence of a `dataregvalue` in the first row, then the difference between the next dataregvalue and the previous one. Next to this data I would like to have the first timestamp in which dataregvalue canges. An example of the select would be:

```
data_change     timestamp             
---------------------------
0                1507190476    <- first time in which the dataregvalue is 0    
1                1507190719    <- first time in which the dataregvalue changes        
1                1507190861    <- first time in which the dataregvalue changes        
3                1507190477    <- first time in which the dataregvalue changes
```

If this is too difficult, it would be fine to have the information about the difference between dataregvalues in a new column like this:

```
dataregvalue      data_change      timestamp             
---------------------------------------------
    0             0                1507190476
    1             1                1507190719
    2             1                1507190861
    5             3                1507190477
```

How can this be done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please review your examples? Where does data_change 3 comes from? Why is 1 listed twice and 5 not listed at all in example 1? Furthermore, are we talking about a real timestamp or is it something created by the delivering system? In other words: can we calculate with it?

Comment: For the datavalue 5, are you sure you expect timestamp 1507190861? First time it changes from 2 to 5, is 1507190477 according to your data.

Comment: Tyron78, the data_changes are the difference between the dataregvalue at that timestamp and its previous. So if at timestamp = 1507190983 the dataregvalue is 2, the next at timestamp 1507190477 is 5, the difference between 5 and 2 is 3. That is why 3 occurs. Rigerta Demiri you are right. I update the question.

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2? You should have used the correct tag. It's no longer supported anyway, the earliest supported version is 2012. Since 2016 SP1 you can have compression, columnstores, in-memory tables even in Express - you could replace some production 2K8R2 databases with Express nowadays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) analytic function to read the previous value in a partition, eg :

```
Select 
    dataregvalue,
    dataregvalue - LAG(dataregvalue,1) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as data_change,
    timestamp
from MyTable
```

This will return the change on all rows. The rows where there is a change will have a `data_change` value >0. The first row will have a NULL value because there is no previous row.

Unfortunately, you can't refer to `data_change` in the WHERE clause. You'll have to use a CTE :

```
WITH changes as (
    Select 
        dataregvalue,
        dataregvalue - LAG(dataregvalue,1) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as data_change,
        timestamp
    from MyTable
)
select * 
from changes
where 
    data_change >0 or 
    data_change is null
```

The `LAG` and the corresponing `LEAD` functions can be used to detect gaps and islands in a sequence as well. Each row will have an ID that is one greater than the previous one. In a gap, the difference will be >1.